# How to create a Google App Engine PHP Restful API service?

Tags: php, rest, google-app-engine

I am trying to create a Restful API page in Google App Engine using PHP that allows an outside entity to send data to it. I started by testing everything first in the Chrome extension "Advanced Rest Client" which accepted the data and returns a response. Then I created the following html so I could test it with Javascript,

```
<html><head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>    
</head>
<body>
<span id="response"></span>
<script>
  var url = "https://www.website.com/api/"
  var data = { "test":"success", };
  var response = function(data){ $("#response").html(data); };
  $.post(url, data, response);
</script>
</body></html>
```

The server is set to return a PHP echo response of "success" or "failure".

1. I tried the above script in Google App Engine and it worked without issue, it accepted the data and returned a response.
2. Then I created a web page at 000webhost.com and tested the code there, it accepted the data but won't return a response.
3. I then sent the code to the person who needs to send data and when they tried it, it said they were unauthorized and no data was accepted.
4. I then tried the following website, https://resttesttest.com/, my server accepts the data, but instead of returning a response, I get the following error,

> Oh no! Javascript returned an HTTP 0 error. One common reason this
>   might happen is that you requested a cross-domain resource from a
>   server that did not include the appropriate CORS headers in the
>   response.

I tried adding the following to my app.yaml with no success,

```
http_headers:
 Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
 Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
```

Any ideas?

Comment: For cross domain request is the server that needs to accept calls from other origins. If using apache you can put  something like `Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` in the .htaccess

Comment: @AndreaG Google App Engine does not run apache and @Mike already said he used `Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`

Comment: Sorry my bad... i'm a little sleepy tonight... but, i think that the problem is there... the `*` has to be `"*"`  so, the yaml should look like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"`

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Turns out the issue was that GAE didn't like my http_headers lines with or without the ". I update through a non-verbose batch and if I'm not paying attention I don't realize it doesn't update. I removed both and added header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' ); to the php.

Answer (score 0):

It was the following causing the issue,

```
http_headers:
 Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
 Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
```

Google App Engine wouldn't accept these parameters so I just used the following line in my PHP,

```
header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' );
```

It works now.

Answer (score 0):

In app.yaml, `http_headers` must come under a specific handler specification in `handlers`, not "stand-alone" as you appear to be using it.

The example suggested in the docs is, specifically:

```
handlers:
- url: /images
  static_dir: static/images
  http_headers:
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'
```

but of course you could apply it to other kinds of handlers too, not just static serving as in the example.